# how to suppress "Duplicate primary key" error message in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I have created student attendance application in MS access 2010 in which I have two main tables. One table is master data of student and other is attendance table in which field ID Card Number and Date is Primary because to avoid duplication of attendance on same day.

One form form scanning is directly attached with attendance table in which when student scan twice the below error shown on screen:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successfully because the would create duplicate value in the index, primary key, or relationship. change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again

In attendance FORM I write my own message in `ON ERROR` control which is working and display error but when I press okay the above screen again appear. I want to suppress the above error message.

Comment: I think that you are using VBA not vb.net so please use the correct tags when you post questions

Comment: If you want us to help with your code, you'll need to show it to us.

Comment: Simply suppressing the error message is almost **always** the wrong approach...

Comment: What is an "on error control" ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

In the `Before Update` event handler for the form I have

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If DCount("*", "Attandence of Employee Lunch", "[RFID Number]=" & Me.RFID_Number) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Primary key already exists."
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Note that the `Cancel = True` statement cancels the update .

Comment: Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If DCount( _
        "*", _
        "Attandence of Employee Lunch", _
        "[RFID Number]=""" & Replace(Me.RFID_Number, """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare) & """" _
        ) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Primary key already exists."
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Comment: in my case Table1 = Attandence of Employee Lunch
Numeric Field = RFID Number

Comment: If [RFID Number] is numeric then you don't need the extra quotes or the `Replace()`. Try just using `"[RFID Number]=" & Me.RFID_Number` as the third argument to the `DLookUp()` function.

Comment: Can u please write the whole Code again, as i still receive errors Thanks ,,,

Comment: Method or Data Member not found "Error"